# Python Twitter json text filter

Tags: python, twitter

Using streaming API from Twitter, I could obtain JSON format data.
However, I have difficulty to filter the certain keywords out from the data set using python. Following is what I have done.

First I defined empty string and lists for filtering:

```
tweets=[]
tweetStr=''
tweetsFiltered=[]
```

Then what I did is open json file, append it on tweets=[] following:

```
for line in open('apple.json'):
    try:
        tweets.append(json.loads(line))
    except:
        pass
```

Then for tweet data, I hope to filter the keyword and erase

```
filterKeyword=['eat','cinnamon','fruit','pie','juice']
for tweet in tweets:
    for tweet['text'] in tweet:
        for key in filterKeyword:
            if key in tweet['text']:
                pass
            else:
                tweetsFiltered.append(tweet)
                tweetStr+=str(tweet['text'])
print(tweetStr)
```

But it returns me only the keys in JSON file (I think it is dictionary key) like this

timestamp_mstimestamp_mstimestamp_mstimestamp_mstimestamp_msretweetedretweetedretweetedretweetedretweetedin_reply_to_user_id_strin_reply_to_user_id_strin_reply_to_user_id_strin_reply_to_user_id_strin_reply_to_user_id_strtruncatedtruncatedtruncatedtruncatedtruncatedretweeted_statusretweeted_status

In this code, how can I **remove the certain keywords** and keep the main data **"tweets"** or add it **tweetStr**??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one redundant loop in your code "for tweet['text'] in tweet".
Here is right code:

```
filterKeyword=['eat','cinnamon','fruit','pie','juice']
for tweet in tweets:
    for key in filterKeyword:
        if key in tweet['text']:
            pass
        else:
            tweetsFiltered.append(tweet)
            tweetStr+=str(tweet['text'])
print(tweetStr)
```

Comment: It's still returning the filterKeyword :( should I share the data file that I want to manipulate?